# Writing safe copy-constructor with smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, smart-pointers

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to write a safe copy constructor with help of `std::unique_ptr` inside.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
  A():_a(10){
    std::cerr << "A() constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  A(const A& tmp){
    _a = tmp._a;
    std::cerr << "A() copy constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  ~A(){
    std::cerr << "~A()" << std::endl;
  }

  int _a;
};

class B {
public:
  B():_b(5){
    std::cerr << "B() constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  B(const B& tmp){
    std::cerr << "B() copy constructor" << std::endl;
    throw std::exception("exc");
  }

  ~B(){
    std::cerr << "~B()" << std::endl;
  }

  int _b;
};

class C {
public:
  C():a(nullptr),b(nullptr){
    std::cerr << "C() constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  C(const C& tmp){
    std::cerr << "C() copy constructor" << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<A> _a(new A(*tmp.a));
    std::unique_ptr<B> _b(new B(*tmp.b));

    a = _a.release();
    b = _b.release();
  }
  ~C(){
    std::cerr << "~B()" << std::endl;
  }

  A* a;
  B* b;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
  c.a = &a;
  c.b = &b;
  C c2(c);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output for this code:

```
A() constructor
B() constructor
C() constructor
C() copy constructor
A() copy constructor
B() copy constructor
```

So, the question is why does A destructor not called? 

As I suppose, `std::unique_ptr<A> _a` will go out of the scope and object should be destroyed.

Comment: if you need a copy constructor, `unique_ptr` is not your smartpointer of choice

Comment: `So, the question is why does A destructor not called? ` Because you throw in `B`'s copy constructor.

Comment: @101010 One would still expect to cause this the dtor of `_a` to fire, though.

Comment: Please note that leading underscores are reserved. Trailing underscores are fine, e.g. `a_` instead of `_a`.

Comment: @JonHarper No, they're not. Leading underscores are reserved *in the global scope,* or if followed by an uppercase letter. But a local or member variable named `_a` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Angew Okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack unwinding is only guaranteed if the exception is ever caught. If you add a try-catch block to your `main`, you will see that the destructors get called correctly.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53925b7e263f2d4d)